# How to use queries in a loop with sails.js async structure?

Tags: performance, asynchronous, sails.js

I'm new to MVC programming and also to Sails.Js, and I'm sure I'm not using it the right way.

What I want to do is to ask my database some informations, create an array with that and then return the data to the view.

Here is what I do:

```
model.exports = {
    'parse': function(req, res) {
        var week = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

        Elements.find({ date : {'>=' : start_date, '<' : end_date }}).exec(function countCB(error, found) {
            while (found.length){   

                week[found.date]++;                     
                total++;

                found.pop();
            };          

            res.view('static/emissions', {  data : week }); 
        });
    };
};
```

Here is how Id' like to do, but the async structure of Node make it fail:

```
model.exports = {
    'parse': function(req, res) {

        var week = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

        for (var day = 0; day < 7; day++){
            Elements.count({ date : {'>=' : start_date + day, '<' : end_date + day }}).exec(function countCB(error, count) {
                week[day] = count;                      
            });
        };

        res.view('static/emissions', {  data : week });
    };
};
```

So am I doing it rigth with the first method ? If no, could you please give me an example that show how to do it correctly ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to do what I wanted using the mongodb aggregate native method.